# Type '() => WebrtcProvider' is not assignable to type 'YjsRealtimeProvider | (() => YjsRealtimeProvider)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was trying to use the YjsExtension in remirror, so I initialized a ydoc and provider like below

```js
const ydoc = new Y.Doc();
const provider = new WebrtcProvider('remirror-yjs-demo', ydoc);
```

and finally adding them to the extensions list this way

```js
new YjsExtension({ getProvider: () => provider }),
```

but I'm getting this type error

```js
Type '() => WebrtcProvider' is not assignable to type 'YjsRealtimeProvider | (() => YjsRealtimeProvider)'.
Type '() => WebrtcProvider' is not assignable to type '() => YjsRealtimeProvider'.Call signature return types 'WebrtcProvider' and 'YjsRealtimeProvider' are incompatible.
The types of 'doc.gcFilter' are incompatible between these types.
Type '(arg0: import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg0: import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item) => boolean'.
Types of parameters 'arg0' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item'.
Types of property 'parent' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/ID").ID | import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any> | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/ID").ID | import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any> | null'.
Type 'AbstractType<any>' is not assignable to type 'ID | AbstractType<any> | null'.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any>'.
Types of property 'doc' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/Doc").Doc | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/Doc").Doc | null'.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/Doc").Doc' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/Doc").Doc'.
Types of property 'gcFilter' are incompatible.
Type '(arg0: import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg0: import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item) => boolean'.
Types of parameters 'arg0' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/structs/Item").Item'.
Types of property 'parent' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/ID").ID | import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any> | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/utils/ID").ID | import("/Users/shamimfahad/code/remirror-test/node_modules/remirror/node_modules/yjs/dist/src/types/AbstractType").AbstractType<any> | null'.
Type 'AbstractType<any>' is not assignable to type 'ID | AbstractType<any> | null'.
```

how do i resolve this?

i'm using

- "@remirror/react": "^1.0.15",
- "@remirror/styles": "^1.1.2",
- "remirror": "^1.0.43",
- "y-webrtc": "^10.2.2",
- "yjs": "^13.5.22"

Comment: So you expect to be able to use a WebrtcProvider instead of YjsRealtimeProvider ?

Comment: according to the [docs](https://remirror.io/docs/extensions/yjs-extension/) here, they both should be compatible with each other

Comment: Oh then their type information is just incomplete or wrong. You can ignore the type error with @ts-ignore. Or write provider as YjsRealtimeProvider